# Eigenvalue of Compact Operators

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, self-learning, spectral-theory

To prove that the set of eigenvectors of a compact linear operator on a normed space $X$ is countable, I read ***"it suffices to show that for every real $k > 0$ the set of all eigenvalues whose absolute values are greater than or equal to $k$ is finite"***. I cannot see why this is true. Even if the quoted statement is true, it may still be possible to have uncountablely many eigenvalues between $-k$ and $k$. Right? What stops this from happening? I must missed something here. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the statement was that it suffices to show that the set of eigenvalues with **absolute value** greater than or equal to $k$ is finite?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are right. I corrected my question. However, I still do not see how this change anything at all.

Comment: Hint: In particular, for every integer $n$, the set of eigenvalues whose absolute values are greater than or equal to $1/n$ is finite.  Call this set $A_n$.  What can you say about the union $\bigcup_n A_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that this is true for *every* $k$ gives you a lot more information than you're considering.  Let's follow Nates comment.

Define $A_n$ to be the set of eigenvalues whose magnitude is greater than $1/n$.  By our statement, each $A_n$ is finite, and so certainly qualifies as "at most countable".

Now, consider the set $S$ of all non-zero eigenvalues.  Well, if $\lambda > 0$, then $|\lambda| > 1/n$ for *some* value of $n$, which means that $\lambda \in A_n$.  So, we may in fact state that 
$$
S \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n
$$
but each $A_n$ is countable, so $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ has to be countable.  So, the set of non-zero eigenvalues is certainly countable.

$0$ might be an eigenvalue, but at any rate: the set of all eigenvalues is certainly a subset of $\{0\} \cup S$, which is countable.  The conclusion follows.